# How to decompile protobuff files with unknown structure

Tags: vb.net, serialization, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to get the raw data from a protobuff file. I've found a few online repositories  (eg. Protobuff dot net) but they require you to initialise a class or structure to deserialise the file into. In my instance this is a bit of a problem as (1) I don't know the structure and (2) it's very likely to change frequently.

Is there any way around trying to deserialise a file without a known structure/class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Google Protocol Buffers datagram without .proto file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627069/parse-google-protocol-buffers-datagram-without-proto-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get limited information by using the `protoc` tool's `--decode_raw` flag:

```
protoc --decode_raw < data.pb
```

However, without type information, you'll only see numeric tags and best guesses at types. But, this is the best you can do -- protobuf is efficient because it avoids putting much type information on the wire, instead relying on both ends to already know the type.