# How do I send a gRPC request if there are no proto files?

Tags: python, grpc

I recently analyzed the Zenly application via mitmproxy, it turned out that it works on gRPC, I was able to extract the payload of the request. I want to emulate this request using Python with my own parameters. For example, there is such a URL:
`https://secret.zenly.rpc.com/co.znly.users.services.sessions.SessionsService/SessionCreate`, the request to which sends an SMS with a confirmation code. The payload for calling this function is as follows:

```
{
"PhoneNumber": "secret",
  "device": {
    "appVersion": "4.63.14",
    "type": "ANDROID", 
    "osVersion": "12",
    "model": "secret",
    "acceptLanguages": "en-US;q=1.0",
    "coreVersion": "1.96.7",
    "appBundle": "app.zenly.locator"
  },
  "deviceOsUuid": "secret",
  "carrierInformations": {
    "networkOperatorCode": "25001",
    "networkOperatorName": "MTS",
    "networkCountryIso": "ru",
    "simOperatorCode": "25001",
    "simOperatorName": "MTS RUS",
    "simCountryIso": "ru"
  }
}
```

So, how to send all this to the server correctly, in serialized (?) a format without Proto-files?

p.s.
grpc_requests and grpcurl did NOT fit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Google Protocol Buffers datagram without .proto file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627069/parse-google-protocol-buffers-datagram-without-proto-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can reference my answer in this question: [How to create GRPC client directly from protobuf without compiling it into java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61133529/how-to-create-grpc-client-directly-from-protobuf-without-compiling-it-into-java/65641262#65641262), it should wrok in python also.

Comment: can you send a Python-code example? i can't figure out from your answer how to use this in Python